# Easy way to insert entire resultset into another DB?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am currently writing a Java program that maintains connections to two SQLlite databases. I need to fetch a large result from one DB and insert it into a table in the other database.

Each DB has it's own thread servicing requests for its database. Currently I take the result from the query from DB1 and convert the resultset into a `List<HashMap<String,Object>>`, where each item in the list is a row and each item in the hashmap is a column name and the associated data. Each row consists of a timestamp and value columns. I cycle through the `List<HashMap<>>` and construct the insert query for DB2 using the following:

```
public String insertDataIntoTrend(ResultData a, int configId) {
    String query = "";
    String adder = "";
    if (a.getData().isEmpty() == false) {
        errorLog.info("Start");
        for (HashMap<String, Object> b : a.getData()) {
            adder = adder + "(" + configId + ", " + b.get("timestamp") + ", " + b.get("value") + "),";
        }
        errorLog.info("End");
        // Remove extra comma
        adder = adder.substring(0, adder.length() - 1);

        query = "insert or ignore into TrendData (configId, timestamp, value) VALUES " + adder;
    }
    return query;
}
```

`a.getData()` is the `List<HashMap>`. This takes 9 minutes for 63000 entries.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Or is it possible to insert an entire resultset without constructing a new insert query row by row?

TLDR: I'm trying to do `Insert DB2.table VALUES(Select timestamp,value from DB1.table)` on two separate DB's. Is there a way to easily construct an insert query for an entire resultset?

Comment: There are several things that you can do to improve the performance instead of using one insert concat 1000 for example, and if you only want to migrate data is better to use sql Scripts than java code

Comment: Got ideas? I dont think it is sql having the problem with the massive query, its java constructing it. But i still think it constructing 63 queries of 1000 items will still yield the same delay.